# How do I add one more field to MongoDB document using php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to upload an image to existing document.(By adding one more field.) I am finding my document through email input.
Here is my code:-

```
<?php

 $errors = array();
 $data = array();
 $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

 $name=$__POST["mn"];
 $email=$__POST["me"];
 $i2u=$_POST["image2upload"];

 $binary = base64_decode($i2u);
 $filepath = 'images/newuploads/'.$name.'/'.$name.'.jpg';
 $imgurl = 'http://localhost/portfolio3/php/'.$filepath;
 file_put_contents($filepath, $binary);

 $m = new MongoClient();
 $db = $m->mydb2->mycol2;
 $foundRecord = $db->find(array('Email'=>$email));      

 $foundRecord->update(array(‘$set’ => array(‘uploadpic1’ => new MongoBinData(file_get_contents($imgurl)))));

?>
```

How do I add one more field to MongoDB document using php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you are searching for only one record, you should use `$db->findOne`

You can then do the following:

```
 $foundRecord = $db->findOne(array('Email'=>$email));
 $foundRecord['uploadpic1'] = new MongoBinData(file_get_contents($imgurl);
 $db->save($foundRecord);
```

Because you used `findOne` it will save to the fetched record instead of creating a new record when using `$db->save($foundRecord);`

Else, if you want to use `update` you need to specify the query in it:

```
$db->update(array('Email'=>$email), array('$set' => array('uploadpic1' => new MongoBinData(file_get_contents($imgurl)))));
```